# Flutter riverpod: too many rebuilds for StreamProvider/FutureProvider combination

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Using `flutter_riverpod`, given the following providers:

```
final s = StreamProvider.autoDispose<bool>((ref) async* {
  yield true;
});

final f = FutureProvider.autoDispose<bool>((ref) async {
  final source = await ref.watch(s.last);
  print('Stream value received: $source');
  return source;
});
```

When `f` is referenced from a `Widget`, it will print the message twice, i.e. it will rebuild twice, even though the referenced `StreamProvider`'s stream only emits a single value.

```
Stream value received: true
Stream value received: true
```

Why is that? How can I make sure that my `FutureProvider` will only run once for each emitted stream value?

Here is the full minimal code to reproduce the issue:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final s = StreamProvider.autoDispose<bool>((ref) async* {
  yield true;
});

final f = FutureProvider.autoDispose<bool>((ref) async {
  final source = await ref.watch(s.last);
  print('Stream value received: $source');
  return source;
});

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: (MyApp())));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    watch(f);
    return const Text('hi');
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it was a bug, but I am using riverpod: ^1.0.0-dev.10, and it prints only once.